# import sometimes returns path and sometimes returns content of file of the path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found a weird behaviour on importing files in React and can't figure out why the two different environments behave differently. Has someone an explanation on where I should start digging here?

Basically I want to load a `test.yaml` file in my React app (just React, no node.js) which works with an import statement in CodeSandbox:

```
import test from "./test.yaml";
```

Content of test is the text of the yaml file, which is what I want.

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-clarke-6f16w?file=/src/index.js

When I copy all the files locally onto my computer and use npm install and npm start the behaviour changes and the content of `test` after the import is the file name with a hash but not the content. I can easily fetch the content of the file later with get-command. I just can't explain why on all the local envs that I tried i have this behaviour.

```
test.yaml as String:  /static/media/test.438607f4.yaml
test.yaml as Object /static/media/test.438607f4.yaml
```

Any ideas?